# Logic Functions with C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, logic

Note on adanve: C++11 is accepted, too, but C++99 preferred. Please no answers with virtual functions, only templates please!

What I'd like to model is a typical "A and B implies C" situation. I have some C++ classes, and some templates describing their properties. Example:

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename U>
class Base
{
    MaybeTruePropertyA<S,T> a;
    MaybeTruePropertyB<S,T,U> b;
    MaybeTruePropertyC<S,T,U> c;
};
```

Lets say I inherit like this:

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename U>
class Inherited : public Base<S,T,U>
{
    TruePropertyA<S,T> a;
    TruePropertyB<S,T, U> b;
};
```

Then I want *magically* to be set `PropertyC` to be of `TrueProperty` in `Inherited`.
Now, here are my problems:

1. I don't know how to do this *magically*.
2. Also, I think it is waste of memory to hide `MaybeTruePropertyA` in Inherited.

Has someone a solution how I can do some "A and B implies C" with Properties like above? You may change some things, but Properties should still be denoted like `TrueProperty<S,T> a`.

A less abstract example can be found here: http://pastebin.com/M209CJp4

Comment: on a side note, MaybeTruePropertyA,B,C are private in Base and so they canät be seen in Inherited. secondly I don´t understand what it means " want magically to be set PropertyC to be of TrueProperty in Inherited". but more important you don´t need to "hide" MaybeTruePropertyA in Inherited, since its already hidden

Comment: Is it ok for Base to have template parameters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure whatever you need can be done with a few simple trait checks (such as `std::is_base_of`), but I don't really understand the precise requirements here...

Comment: @VaughnCato: Sure, this is okay! You can add as many templates as you like.

Comment: @KerrekSB That also was my first idea when reading this, but implies the OP want's to have a static check for this, which isn't cleared out in the question.

Comment: @Johannes Can you please explain a bit more what you want to achieve from a use case or client API view. That'll help a lot to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Johannes As for your 2. point I also would consider providing unused properties from your base class a waste of memory.

Comment: @g-makulik The idea was to have some algebraic structures which had some properties. In my case, there were UFDs (unique factoring domains) and Dedekind rings. If a ring `R` is an UFD and a Dedekind ring, one can proof that `R` is a PID (principal ideal domain). No need to understand that. But let's say a user inherits from the ring base class and gives it the properties "UFDprops" and "Dedekindprops", like above. There should be a member "PIDProps", so we can use the properties of a PID. So, PIDProperties.doSomething() will behave different in the Bass class and the inherited class.

Comment: "You can add as many templates as you like."  That's a dangerous thing to say around here. :-O

Comment: `A call of c.doSomething() shall behave different in Base and Inherited`: Isn't that a textbook need for polymorphism? If you cannot use runtime polymorphism (`virtual`) for some reason, what about compile-time via CRTP instead of trying to set properties? Also, how do you instantiate `MaybeTruePropertyA<S,T>` given that `S` and `T` are not compile-time constants?

Comment: @MarkB I fully agree, further CRTP implementations may implement traits for static concept checking, even better the CRTP bases do this.

Comment: C++99 would be hard to come around... you might be referring to C++98 or maybe C++03. Besides that, you should really work on the question, it is **very unclear** what you want to do. It is unclear what the properties are, how they are used. Can you provide a high level description of what you want to achieve? An example?

Comment: Your pseudocode and its accompanying description has some issues, namely there's no `PropertyC` and you can't use `S` and the others as template parameters. It's been asked before, but I feel I must insist: can you express your requirements in English? Or perhaps with simple code expressions that doesn't show the implementation of `Base` and `Inherited`?

Comment: @Johannes What's your primary reason to avoid virtual polymorphism for your solution?

Comment: @LucDanton I think you are right... The S,T,U should be classes instead! Classes which were passed as template parameters... I think one could leave them out for easiness. I'll soon have the S,T,U corrected and I'll try to come up with more code... Thanks for now.

Comment: @Johannes I would appreciate some more details (as also requested in my previous comments). I'm most worrying about your nebulous _magically instantiate some functionaltity_ approach. There's nothing _magical_ in template meta-programming techniques they're following strict rules of course: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming)

Comment: I added some real code now, please follow the pastebin links... Sorry, I think I really should have done this before :(

Comment: @g-makulik I like to avoid virtual functions because they may have runtime issues, and also, I want to learn about templates. Hopefully, the pastebin link is a bit more detailled :)

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to accomplish, but is http://ideone.com/TWRWI close to what you had in mind?

Comment: @Johannes I tried to compile your code and after initializing `equation` in the `do_experiments()` method the code compiles fine. So can you explain exactly what doesn't behave as you expect to do? BTW I don't think that this is too much code as to provide it as sample in your question.

Comment: @user315052 Thanks, it gets very close, but I think I looked for something different. As far as I got it, you allow to set properties to true or false in the Base class constructor (and similar in Inherited), and make boolean requests (line 35). I'd like to get rid of boolean requests, having the answer to them in templates. Is this possible?

Comment: @g-makulik The issue is that `both.pid.easifyEquation(equation)` calls `Property::easifyEquation(const char*)`. It should call `TrueProperty::easifyEquation(const char*)` instead, because `both` is a PID (since it is both UFD and Dedekind).

Comment: @Johannes: It seems you want template specialization then.

Comment: @user315052: Yes, after 3 hours of thinking, that's *exactly* what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really follow the code in your paste bin. It doesn't even really follow the example in your toy code in your question. But, it seems what you are after is template specialization based on parameters to your property templates. Below is an example of how you might accomplish this:

```
template <int S, int T> struct PropertyA { enum { V = false }; };
template <int S, int T, int U> struct PropertyB { enum { V = false }; };
```

The idea is that `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` are `false` properties by default. They are made `true` through specialization, illustrated later.

```
template <bool A, bool B>
struct PropertyC {
    void doSomething () { std::cout << "False" << std::endl; }
};

template <> struct PropertyC<true, true> {
    void doSomething () { std::cout << "True" << std::endl; }
};
```

Here, `PropertyC` behaves as a `false` property unless both its parameters are `true`. This was accomplished with specialization.

```
template <int S, int T, int U>
struct MaybeTruePropertyC {
    void doSomething () {
        PropertyC<PropertyA<S, T>::V, PropertyB<S, T, U>::V>().doSomething();
    }
};
```

Now, `MaybeTruePropertyC` is parameterized by values used by `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`, and their values are fed to `PropertyC` to get the desired behavior.

So, to use the classes, you would define some specializations for `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`.

```
template <> struct PropertyA<1, 2> { enum { V = true }; };
template <> struct PropertyB<1, 2, 3> { enum { V = true }; };
```

And you can now use it like this:

```
MaybeTruePropertyC<1, 2, 3> c;
c.doSomething();
```

You can follow the [link](http://ideone.com/sTmV4) to see the code in action.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I have been looking for. Do I get it right that the compiler in line 18 first tries to match PropertyC<true, true>, and if one of the template parameters is false, then it matches Property<bool, bool>?

Comment: @Johannes: Essentially. There are four types associated with the `PropertyC<bool, bool>` template. All of them are treated the same except for the specialization for `PropertyC<true, true>`.

Comment: Ah, I think this technique is called "Traits" in C++. Correct?

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, you can consider the value of `V` to be a trait.